# JButtons in GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I'm a beginner in GUI.

Is there a quick way of  setting the same JButton/Image to multiple locations within the GUI? For better clarification, if I want to use this JButton 10 times at different locations in my GUI, would I have to create a new JButton(new ImageIcon...) 10 times?

The buttons don't have to lead to anything, this is just for show.

```
JButton jb = new JButton(new ImageIcon("myImage.png"));
jb.setLocation(10,10);
jb.setSize(40, 40);
getContentPane().add(jb);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is, yes, you will need multiple instances of `JButton`.

You can use an `Action` which can be applied to multiple instance of a button (the same instance of `Action`).  The `Action` class carries properties which will be used to configure the buttons, such as text and icon properties.

A component (like `JButton`) can only reside within in a single container, therefore, you will need multiple instances of `JButton`.

Take a look at [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) and [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more details...

Generally, you should avoid using `setLocation` and `setSize` and rely more on the use of layout managers, but you've not provided enough context to say if this useful to you or not.

Comment: This is just one approach, it might be worthwhile trying a few of the other suggestions as well as see how they differ for your own experience ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to create a Jbutton object for each desired instance.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have so many `JButton` that are all similar, I suggest that you declare an array `JButton[] buttons = new JButton[10];` and use a for loop to create each individual button and set their attributes.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just for a show, I would do the following to show the 10 button in a row:

```
int buttonHeight = 10;
int buttonWidth = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    JButton button = new Button("Button " + i);
    button.setSize(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
    button.setLocation(10 + i * buttonWidth, 10);
    getContentPane().add(button);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;

 class PROB4_CHAL1 extends JFrame 
 {
    JButton b[]=new JButton[10];
        public PROB4_CHAL1()
        {
            setLayout(null);
            setVisible(true);
            setSize(100,100);
          for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
           {
           b[i]=new JButton(""+i);// or b[i]=new JButton(new ImageIcon("path"));
           b[i].setBounds(i*10,i*20,50,20);
           add(b[i]);
           }

        }

       public static void main(String[] args)
        {
         new PROB4_CHAL1();
          }
   }
```

You can Create array of 'JButton [10]' .[image]